# How to freeze column of grid in sencha touch 2.3.0

Tags: grid, sencha-touch-2

I follow this tutorial

http://www.lincolnwaterfrontrentals.com/Sencha/TTG_Freeze/app.html

but I have problem for grid column sort

Please suggest me any other alternative way for freeze column of grid in sencha touch 2.3.0